# regex find double or single quotes in start and end of each word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find out who many words or set of words are enclosed either in single quotes or double quotes.

I tested it using the below regex pattern for double quotes. However, the issue remains same, even if I have a word starting with single double quote and ending with two double quotes, it is giving me the output value. I am expecting other than enclosed with two double quotes for each word what ever extra quotes are there should find as I have to remove those extra quotes.

```
f = '"country id""   "state id"'

print(re.findall('^".*["\s"][a-z].*"$',f))
```

Comment: So, you have `"country id""   "state id"` as input, what is the expected output?

Comment: expected output should be nothing or false because each set of words only enclosed one set of single or double quote but in the above example first word ends with two double quotes then it must give nothing.

Comment: So, something like `^\s*"[^"]*"(?:\s*"[^"]*")*\s*$`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yz53dn/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\s*"[^"]*"(?:\s*"[^"]*")*\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yz53dn/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more (here, leading) whitespaces
- `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, zero or more chars other than `"`, and then a `"`
- `(?:\s*"[^"]*")*` - zero or more sequences of zero or more whitespaces and then substrings between `"` chars having no other `"` inside them
- `\s*` - zero or more (here, trailing) whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

If there are escape sequences, you will need to amend it to

```
^\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(?:\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")*\s*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQohlT/1).

Here, `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` is used instead of `"[^"]*"` to match

- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of any escaped char (other than a line break char) and then zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `"` - a `"` char